# Center a div that has a display value set to inline-block

Tags: html, css

[image]

As seen in the picture above the posts are not centered.
I tried these solutions that i found on the net but none worked:

- Setting wrapper div to `position: relative;`  and child div to `position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`
- Doing `position: absolute; display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;` on the wrapper div.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Always post the least minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Set `text-align: center;` on the container.

Comment: ... and ditch all the superfluous `position: absolute; ... etc` stuff

Comment: Setting text-align: center;  on the container centered them but now they are no longer inline.

Comment: CD001, yea my bad!

Answer (score 3):

Have a container and set the text-align to center:

```
<div id="container" style="text-align:center">
  <div style="display:inline-block">Post 1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block">Post 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't have two posts. It's actually one post looped all over again. so setting text-align: center; will make them centered but they will no longer be inline.

Comment: What does "one post looped all over again" mean? If the divs have a display of inline-block they can never not be inline....

Comment: here's the code of a simple loop:  
`<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_content();
 } // end while
} / end if
?>`

Comment: it's not two seperate posts, it's one post duplicated with different content

Comment: That means if you set text-align: center; they will both be centered in the same spot.

Comment: while ( have_posts() ) { 
"<div style='display:inline-block'>".the_content()."</div>"; 
} 

Or something like that

Comment: One under the other.

Comment: Yes that's the loop.

Comment: no it's  <div class="posts" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"><?php if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) { the_content(); } // end while } / end if ?>  </div>

Comment: Mister, if you are using an inline-block as a container and then dumping stuff inside it makes no sense for what you want to achieve... every post should be a div with an inline-block display.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't work like static html, the loop is a simply a block of code that displays all of the information that WordPress has about a post(s) or page(s). Like the name suggests, it loops through each post that it finds in the database sequentially (one, then another, then another), so it can handle supplying information about several posts.

Comment: @LineCommanderOfficial - can't you change the loop so that it's something like `<div style="text-align: center;">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) { '<div class="posts" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">' . the_content() . '</div>'; } // end while } / end if ?>
</div>` ?